# Upload image to firebase failed when clicking anything in comfirmation page and the app crash

Tags: android, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage, image-gallery

I have a question about upload image to firebase and it works before and after I done other activity...It failed...Can your guys help me...

The main error was when user click OK or CANCEL in confirmation page, the app crash. App will crash too when user select from gallery...

Here is the logcat...

```
2021-03-30 22:56:16.853 12576-12576/? E/in.firebasetes: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
```

And here is the code for activity...

```
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    userID = user.getUid();
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    UserPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.UserPic);
    UserPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            VerifyPermission();
        }
    if (user != null){
        if (user.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
            Glide.with(this).load(user.getPhotoUrl()).into(UserPic);
        }
    }

}

private void VerifyPermission() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UserProfile.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UserProfile.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);

    }else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        selectOptionList();

    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE){

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            selectOptionList();

        }else {

            Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Camera Permissions is required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
}

private void selectOptionList(){

    selectList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.selectList);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select an option");

    builder.setItems(selectList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){

                case 0:
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    break;

            }
        }
    });

    alertDialog = builder.create();
    builder.show();

}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "interpayment.main.firebasetest.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + userID + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    //File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Opening Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return image;
}

private void uploadImageToFirebase(String name, Uri contentUri) {

    final StorageReference img = storageReference.child("pictures/" + name);
    img.putFile(contentUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            img.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Log.d("100", "onSuccess: Upload Image URL is " + uri);
                    Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setUserProfileUrl(uri);
                }
            });
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

private void setUserProfileUrl(Uri uri) {

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    UserProfileChangeRequest request = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setPhotoUri(uri).build();
    user.updateProfile(request).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Failed set Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {

            File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
            UserPic.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(f));
            Log.d("tag", "Absolute Url of Image is " + Uri.fromFile(f));
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

            uploadImageToFirebase(f.getName(), contentUri);


        }else if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && data != null){

            Uri img = data.getData();
            Log.d("tag", "onActivityResult: Gallery Image Uri:  " + img);
            UserPic.setImageURI(img);

            uploadImageToFirebase(currentPhotoPath, img);

        }

    }

}
```

I appreciate for your guys helping and thanks a lot for taking time to help me. Logcat was like this...

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxomD.png)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
**Update**

My question is solved. The problem was the onStop function, I removed it. This is because the system set the [open camera] and [take photo from gallery] as new actitvity. So, if you have the onStop function, system close the apps when you open camera or others. This cause the apps automatically close and no any error in logcat.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo and I am sorry about that, I have edited the code...Thanks for your advise!

Comment: That's not an Error, nor an Exception. If you see an Exception in your logcat, please add it to your question,

Comment: I have updated the logcat image...Can you take a look and help me... @AlexMamo

Comment: Cannot see any Exception in your logcat. Try to filter by Error in Android Studio, not by Verbose. Do see any Error/Exception?

Comment: Nope...Nothing error...

Comment: And then why do you say that the app crashes?

Comment: The app closed like crash instantly when click ok OR cancel when photo taken...

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks For Helping! I found the error and fixed it~Thanks for your help. Really thanks a lot!

Comment: If you found the problem, add it as an answer, so future visitors can see it ;)

Comment: Noted and thanks for your help. Really thanks!